# Why is there TCP RST packet after sending a string and closing a socket

Tags: python, sockets

I try to use python socket to send char Y and after enter But when I capture wireshark i detect it error. Why?
The code in python:

```
import socket
import re

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = (('pwnable.kr', 9009))
sock.connect((server_address))
b=sock.recv(2048)    # I must use 2 sock.recv then recv full text 
print b
b=sock.recv(2048)
print b
b=re.findall("Y/N",b)
print b
#sock.recv(1024)
if b[0]=="Y/N":
    print "OK"
    sock.send(("Y"+"\r\n").encode())
    b=sock.recv(1024)
```

Wireshark capture:
[image]
How to send string and then enter?
Using multiple sock.recv affect anything?

---

UPDATE1:
I want print last b, it should is

```
Enter 1 to Begin the Greatest Game Ever Played.
Enter 2 to See a Complete Listing of Rules.
Enter 3 to Exit Game. (Not Recommended)
Choice:
```

But i receive null list. 
My code:

```
import socket
import re

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)   
server_address = (('pwnable.kr', 9009))  
sock.connect((server_address))
b=sock.recv(2048)
print b
b=sock.recv(2048)
print b
b=re.findall("Y/N",b)
print b
#sock.recv(1024)
if b[0]=="Y/N":
    print "OK"
    sock.send(("Y"+"\r\n").encode())
    b=sock.recv(1024)
    print b
sock.close()
```

In wireshark have red line:
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the error you think you're getting?  That Wireshark capture looks like your program did exactly what you wanted it to.  If the issue is that ``.[2J.[1;1H`` string, those are ANSI control codes to clear the screen (Wireshark rendered the <ESC> characters as dots).

Comment: And when i use wireshark, it have 1 red last line, it is error?

Answer (score 3):

## What's happening here?

Orderly TCP shutdown looks like this:

- This side sends `FIN` meaning "I have nothing more to send".
- The other side responds `ACK` meaning "OK, got all your data". From this point, reading from the socket on the other side will return empty (meaning "end of file").
- The other side decides it has nothing more to say, sends `FIN` meaning "I have nothing more to send".
- This side sends `ACK` meaning "OK, got all your data".
- Now both sides can close the file descriptor.

But `socket.close` does not do orderly shutdown. It sends `FIN`, waits for an `ACK`, then it closes the descriptor. From this point, any TCP packet to this port will result in a `RST` response meaning "No such connection".

The red line is just a marker for TCP `RST` packet.

## How to avoid the RST packet?

Assuming the remote side eventually closes the connection after its `recv` returns empty (0 bytes available), you can avoid the RST by doing:

```
sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
buf = sock.recv(1)
if not buf:
  # Remote side sent FIN.
  sock.close()
# else: more data to handle, should recv again, until it returns empty
```

This way your side will handle everything the other side wants to send and only close once the other side says `FIN`.